# Conditionally Crawling List Items

Tags: fast-search, fast-for-sharepoint

A list with more than thousand items has these columns:

1. Title
2. List item
3. Description
4. URL
5. Expiry Date

When crawling, how do I exclude the list items where the items Expiry Date has passed?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a custom pipeline extensibilty stage to drop it, but not sure I would recommend it. It's probably better to exclude them query time, for example with an fql enabled scope.